# jboss war deployed listener

Tags: jboss, hotdeploy

Is there a single listener one could implement to get a "war deployed" event?

I know there is the [ContextServletListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). 
But it has to be 'attached' for each component (several web.xml files).

As a fallback, if I use ContextServletListener, how can I tell that the last component has been deployed?

As a side note: I need to be aware of a hot deploy when it finishes.

Comment: Which version of JBoss are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBoss registers a **J2EEApplication** MBean when a war is deployed. You can register a JMX notification listener with the JBoss MBeanServer's MBeanServer delegate (Object name: **JMImplementation:type=MBeanServerDelegate**) which will notify you when MBeans are registered and unregistered.

An ObjectName filter like **jboss.management.local:J2EEServer=Local,j2eeType=WebModule,*** for your registered notification listener will get you notifications for all deployed wars.

This will work for JBoss 4.x and 5.x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it could benefit from a few links like [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/jmx:_building_a_jmx_notification) :), an example... etc...

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!